# Spring 3.0 Validation without Hibernate

Tags: spring, validation

Is there a way to automatically validate incoming Models in Spring 3.0 **without using Hibernate**?
I have a CustomValidator which implements the Validator interface and I would like that CustomValidator to be called for each method I specify, such as:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/*")
public class MyController {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{entryId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    protected String editEntry(@PathVariable int entryId, Guestbook guestbook) {
        // Validate Guestbook against CustomValidator
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! But how do I register my Validator with the Controller method?

Comment: all th einfo you need is here http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation

Comment: It doesn't seem like it. I declared the Validation Bean like this:
<bean id="validator"
  class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />

Yet I can't access any of the \@Min, \@NotNull etc annotations.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `@InitBinder` might help you.

Answer (score 0):

To enable validate on spring MVC without hibernate validator you need do follow thing:

1. Define validator implement Spring Validator interface
2. Register Validator with Controller through global config or for each controller. For each controller you need define annotation callback method @InitBinder
3. Annotation model attribute need validate with @Valid and add parameter BindingResult to get result

If you still feel hard to do make it work, Please check detail on this post:[Spring MVC Form Validation using Validator](http://devjav.com/spring-mvc-form-validation-using-validator/)